# How to store all keys/values of a NSDitionary in a string

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a NSDictionary object containing key/value pairs. I want to be able to out them to a UITextView each in a new line. How would one get about doing that?

Thanks

Comment: This is such an elementary question I'm stunned someone would ask it. One could easily iterate through the dictionary  creating UITextViews and setting the text.

Comment: @David Tay  sometimes you should help even with such elementary questions.

Comment: Agree.   Every question is "elementary" once you know how to do it.  Since when is SO limited to non-"elementary" questions?

Comment: It is elementary because I am new to Objective C. Not denying that fact. Thank You for taking the time to comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableString* str = [NSMutableString string];
for(NSString* key in dict) {
  [str appendFormat: @"%@ - %@\n", key, [dict valueForKey: key]];
}

textView.text = str;
```